# QtCreator ClangCodeModel does not work when using a compiler other than MSVC on Windows

Tags: c++, qt-creator, llvm-clang

More specifically I think this relates to how qtcreator interacts with the clang code model.

I would like to use qtcreator with clang on windows. I am using a generic project structure and have configured a kit to use the clang compiler.

However, this simple hello world example highlights the error "no member named 'endl' in namespace 'std'" even though it compiles fine.

Does anyone know the steps I must follow to get the code model working with a custom compiler?

This issue is logged as https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-23006.

Thanks,

[image: clang warning]

Comment: What version of Creator are you using? The code model is independent from the kit's compiler. Creator ships with its own version of clang for use by the clang code model plugin. Have you enabled that plugin? See in "Help->About plugins" and search for "clang". Make sure it's enabled there.

(Off-topic: Also, don't use `endl` unless you actually want a shortcut for `<< '\n' << std::flush`.)

Comment: I'm using version 4.9.1 open source.
I think I misunderstood how the code model works. I assumed it would have to be somehow related to the compiler in use so the correct symbols (#defines) are used.
Interestingly, on Windows, when I leave the compiler as MSVC, everything seems to work fine. It is only when I change the kit / compiler to Clang do I see this problem. I'll keep investigating.

Comment: I've done some more digging if you use clang-cl over clang or clang++ when configuring the kit then the code completion seems to work fine. I don't really understand the interaction between the two.

Comment: This is also true for VS Code. I had the same problem using clang, but clang-cl works.

Comment: Final thing, if you open a generic project and get no syntax highlighting at all, try deleting your project folder of all temporaries, such as pro.user files and open the project again

Comment: @NikosC.
Apparently, the static analysis works only when a MSVC compiler is chosen:
https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTCREATORBUG-23006